# How to bind a view control's FormattedText property to its data model

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

Im trying to format my text and keep all style/format code in the view rather than in the data model.

So using a `DataTemplate` I create simply a `Label`.
I want to then format the Label's Text for example with color and bold and prefix it with a constant.
But im unable to figure out what needs to go in the `Span` `Text` property.

```
internal class BleDeviceDiagnosticItemDataTemplate : DataTemplate
{
    internal BleDeviceDiagnosticItemDataTemplate()
    {
        LoadTemplate = static () =>
        {
            Label idLabel = new() { Text = "default text" };
            idLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Id");

            FormattedString formattedId = new();
            formattedId.Spans.Add(new() { Text = ??? , TextColor = Colors.Red, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold });
            idLabel.FormattedText = formattedId;
        }
    }
}
```

So while setting the `Span` `Text` property with a constant works, for example "Some Text":

```
Text = "Some Text"
```

Setting it to the `Label.Text` doesn't:

```
Text = Label.Text;
```

And leaving it out leaves it with no text.

I also tried binding the `Label.FormattedText` property and setting it in the code behind but that didnt work at all.

```
idLabel.SetBinding(Label.FormattedTextProperty, "IdFormattedString");
```

I need advise on how to bind this Text Property to data

Comment: You need to use SetBinding on the span, not the Label

Comment: Would not a style be more appropriate to set the color, weight and other font properties? "FormattedText" seem most useful when you need to style different parts of the string in different ways, but then it seems difficult to separate styling from the data model.

Comment: @JonasH perhaps Style might be more appropriate, but it seems i could use the FormattedText to prefix and suffix Text as well as style all in one place.  Regardless i want to learn to use the FormattedText property, and I want to learn to use it in the view and keep it out of the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Welp i feel kinda cheesy answering my own question here as the answer turns out pretty obvious.... but it seems you just need to bind the data to the `Span` `Text` property, not the `FormattedString`, not to the `Label`.

```
FormattedString formattedId = new();
Span idText = new(){ TextColor = Colors.Orange };
idText.SetBinding(Span.TextProperty, nameof(BleDeviceItem.Id));
formattedId.Spans.Add(idText);
idLabel.FormattedText = formattedId;
```